# The difference between require-jquery and jquery (How to use)

Tags: javascript, jquery, requirejs, require

I am using external js libs thats are not AMD modules so I use shim. Let us use bootstrap.js in this example. bootstrap.js Needs jQuery

```
requirejs.config({
paths : {
    jquery : "lib/jquery",
    bootstrap : "lib/bootstrap",
},

shim : {
    "bootstrap" : [ "jquery" ]
}
});
```

I will also need require-jquery. This means that I will have two jQuery files. One standard and the require-jquery.

If I do this

```
paths : {
   jquery : "jquery-require"
   bootstrap : "lib/bootstrap",
},
```

I will get a jQuery issue
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'fn' of undefined

Could you help me figure out how to use this?

Comment: Sorry fixed. Sorry I usually just say thanks :)

Comment: curious why you'd need both require-jquery & plain jquery? require-jquery just bundles both the require lib itself as well as jquery (at one point there were some minor tweaks to jquery as well but I'm pretty sure that stuff is gone). Anyway, one thing to try: don't map a path to jquery when using the bundled version... it should already be loaded an thus registered under the plain 'jquery' name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use "jquery-require". Your first configuration (using jquery and shim) is enough.

AFAIK jquery-require is a bundle of require+jquery done for the previous versions of requirejs (before 2.0).

You don't need any special configuration for latest versions of Require or jQuery. For example jQuery will export the jQuery global using `define` if its detected (see https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/exports.js).